# Using echo.js render method?

Tags: javascript, plugins, echo.js

Using Todd Motto's [echo.js](https://github.com/toddmotto/echo) plugin for lazy loading. I'm trying to figure out how to use the `.render()` with the plugin. Would I use it like `.init()` or can I chain together?

```
echo.init({
   debounce: false,
   offset: 100,
   throttle: 250,
   unload: false
});

echo.render({
   debounce: false,
   offset: 100,
   throttle: 250,
   unload: false
});

echo.render().init({
   debounce: false,
   offset: 100,
   throttle: 250,
   unload: false
});
```

Comment: Your question should be very easy to answer by simply trying it out.

Comment: @Tomalak you're right... and I have, and it didn't work. I've searched for something more than what the docs have but, was unsuccessful. I haven't come to StackOverflow without trying.

Comment: Okay...  I don't quite understand why it's a problem to call them one after the other?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work. So, I'm looking for help from someone who may have worked with this plugin before.